# Trying to change HTML with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change my HTML code by using JQuery. When I use this code it works:

```
$('.theclass').html('hello');
```

But what I really want to do is to include a  statemente in my HTML. So I tried this but it does not work.

```
$('.theclass').html( 
    "<select name='myName' id='myId'>
        <option value=''>-</option>
        <option value='A'>A</option>
        <option value='B'>B</option>
    </select>"
);
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you put all that on one line? You can't break strings across multiple lines in JavaScript like that.

Comment: `it does not work.` elaborate more.

Comment: It's a basic syntax error. You can't have strings that span multiple lines.

Answer (score 4):

Try to `concatenate` the strings properly when your string input exceeds out to a newer line,

```
$('.typehidden .controls').html( 
    "<select name='myName' id='myId'>"
        + "<option value=''>-</option>"
        + "<option value='A'>A</option>"
        + "<option value='B'>B</option>"
    + "</select>"
);
```

Comment: A little explanation on why this will work would be helpful to the OP

Comment: @asprin Sure.. give me 2 mins..

Comment: No worries, I already +1'd it

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\` to create multline string.

```
$('.theclass').html( 
    "<select name='myName' id='myId'>\
        <option value=''>-</option>\
        <option value='A'>A</option>\
        <option value='B'>B</option>\
    </select>"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

multi line without `+` or `\` operator doesn't work , use either Rajaprabhu answer or you can write in a single line.

```
$('.theclass').html(  "<select name='myName' id='myId'><option value=''>-</option><option value='A'>A</option><option value='B'>B</option></select>");
```